# Python sockets: Connection refused

Tags: python, sockets, serversocket

I'm using the following code to forward strings from server 1 to server 2, and back, opening and closing the socket each time.

```
def ts1(data):
try:
    ts_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    print("CONNECTED TO TS1")
except socket.error as err:
    print('socket open error: {} \n'.format(err))
    exit()

ts_addr = (args.server_location, args.tsport)
ts_sock.connect(ts_addr)



with ts_sock:
    if stuff:
            ts_sock.sendall(ts_data.encode('utf-8'))
            print('sent to ts1: ' + hostname)

    while True:
        data2 = ts_sock.recv(512)
        data2 = data2.decode('utf-8')
        data2 = data2.strip()
        print('data 2: ' + data2)

        break

    ts_sock.close()
    return data2
```

Server 2's socket is created beforehand and is never closed manually, so it just receives data, does it's thing and sends it back:

```
with csockid:
while True:
    # receive and decode
    try:
        data = csockid.recv(512)
        data = data.decode('utf-8')
        data = data.strip()

    except ConnectionResetError:
        print("==> ConnectionResetError")
        pass

    if data:
        csockid.sendall(data.encode('utf-8'))       
        # print('sent')
    if not data:
        break
```

For some reason, the first string is sent and received back just fine, but the second time I try to connect to server 2 and send another string, I get:

```
ts_sock.connect(ts_addr)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Any help would be appreciated, I'm rather new to socket programming & python in general.

Comment: I'm going to guess there's a newline or other whitespace being sent, `strip` reduces that to an empty string, the `if not data` is true and the loop breaks out. Put something like `print(list(data))` right after the call to `recv` and see what prints out.

Comment: The code is not sufficient to reproduce the problem. There is a connection error here which indicates that the server socket is no longer listening. But anything like this is not part of the code shown. It might simply be that your server has crashed though and that's why is no longer listening.